# Generating DDLs during .Net application runtime

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-generation, runtime, ddl

I am planning a .Net application, a part of which involves assisting a user to model an entity and finally have it represented in a physical database (SQL Server).

Basically I want to be able to generate good quality DDL from the model that I capture from the end user. I looked at possibilities with *Entity Framework*, however, it looks like access to Visual Studio is required in that case.

There are several other .Net code generation tools & libraries, but all of then impose the usage restriction to design time. I want this ability at runtime.

If I have answer to the above, I'd like to further have the capability of creating .Net entities to access the newly created data schema ... again at runtime :)

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I was looking at the *Code-Only Development* option with *Entity Framework*. Prima Facie, it looks good as it does not involve technologies like T4 that are available only during design and that too in presence of Visual Studio.

Although this approach too will involve code generation, it looks manageable. A minor catch is that this option is in CTP and not all features available with other 2 approaches (database to model and vice-versa) are completely available.

Please comment.